# crear un objeto con una funcion en javascript

Tags: funciones, variables

¿como puedo hacer que el objeto p lo llame como una funcion p()?

```
var p={
color:"rojo",
saludo:"hola, ¡que tal?!,
}
p("un argumento").color;
```

¿existe alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: eso se hace con una clausura incluso una clase

Comment: ¿pero, no es posible mediante objetos?

Comment: que tal si cierras la pregunta y nos vamos al [chat]

Comment: gracias aunque esa pregunta no me ayudo, investigando mas pude saber como hacerlo